# Columnnames with problematic characters

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm trying to apply a RowFilter to a DataTable but the problem with the DataTable is, there are non usual ColumnNames given. Like some ending on a point or some others have spaces in them and so on.

As an example consider this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Button ClickMe = new Button();
    public DataTable TestTable = new DataTable();
    public DataGridView TestView = new DataGridView();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        TestView.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        ClickMe.Size = new Size(100, 50);
        ClickMe.Text = "Click Me!";
        ClickMe.Location = new Point(100, 400);
        this.Controls.Add(TestView);
        this.Controls.Add(ClickMe);
        TestView.Visible = true;
        TestTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Addressnumb."));
        TestTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondColumn"));
        TestView.DataSource = TestTable;
        ClickMe.MouseClick += ClickMe_MouseClick;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow Row = TestTable.NewRow();
            Row["Addressnumb."] = i.ToString();
            Row["SecondColumn"] = "Text " + i.ToString();
            TestTable.Rows.Add(Row);
        }
    }

    private void ClickMe_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Filtering for SecondColumn");
        TestTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "SecondColumn LIKE '%1'";
        MessageBox.Show("Filtering for Addressnumb.");
        TestTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Addressnumb. LIKE '%1'";
    }

}
```

Is there a way how one can escape the characters or mask them that a RowFilter still can be applied?

Comment: `[Addressnumb.] LIKE '%1'`

Comment: Well thanks :D works in an instant!